# How to add Sub-OUs in Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a Powershell script that creates new student accounts, makes necessary changes to existing accounts and moves the accounts to the correct OU based on school. The script worked pretty well previously because the OU structure was pretty flat. All school OUs were located directly under the "District Student Users" OU.

District Student Users

- OMS
- OHS
- OES

However, now we are getting new schools that don't fit the structure. Instead of being independent school levels, we have added a couple of schools that require sub-OUs. (Indicated under the CompilationSchools).
*edit-Added an additional level of OUs under THS indicated by the "AHS" and "BHS"

- District Student Users
- -----OMS
- -----OHS
- -----OES
- -----CompilationSchools
- ----------TMS
- ----------THS
- -------------AHS
- -------------BHS

---

- ----------TES

The script defines the base OU as $base = "OU="+$ou+",OU=District Student Users,DC=district,DC=edu"

I don't know how to include the necessary sub-OUs in the script while not messing up the existing base OU definition.

```
 # Move AD Object to the new OU
  IF ($newschool -eq 1) {
    Switch ($department)
      {
    "One Middle School" { $ou="OMS" }
    "One High School" { $ou="OHS" }
    "One Elementary" { $ou="OES" }
    default { $ou="z_Unclassified" }
      }
    Write-Host "  Also moved from"$exist.department"to"$department`r
    $base = "OU="+$ou+",OU=District Student Users,DC=district,DC=edu"
    Sleep 2
    Move-ADObject -Identity $dn -TargetPath $base -server $dc }
  ELSEIF ($newschool -eq 2) {
    Write-Host "   Account moved to z_DisabledAccounts OU"`r
    $base = "OU=z_DisabledAccounts,OU=District Student Users,DC=district,DC=edu"
    Sleep 2
    Move-ADObject -Identity $dn -TargetPath $base -server $dc 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `switch` statement:

```
    $compSch= "OU=CompilationSchools"
    Switch ($department)
      {
    "One Middle School" { $ou="OMS" }
    "One High School" { $ou="OHS" }
    "One Elementary" { $ou="OES" }
    "One Compliation HS" { $ou="THS,$compSch" }
    default { $ou="z_Unclassified" }
      }
```

That's the quick and easy solution and it should work fine. The extra variable is just to save a little typing.

If you might have horrible characters in your OU names like commas (I hope not), or just to save confusion, you might want to be a little less lazy and do a proper concatenation of the OU string, similar to how it's done later.

```
"One Compliation HS" { $ou="THS," + $compSch }
```

Comment: This was great and worked like a charm, THANKS! I forgot to add that I have some situations with one more nested level--so under THS, there is an additional level. (*I edited the post to reflect the additional information) I don't know if it was the simplest method to do it that way, but I just defined one more level $thsSch="OU=THS,OU=CompilationSchools" and used that variable for the nested schools.

Comment: No worries, and yes, the good thing about this is that you can just recycle the method down the tree if required. There may come a point where you'd want to be a little more sophisticated, but I think too many OU levels should be avoided anyway. A `switch` statement is certainly nicer than a load of nested `if` statements!